# Return back all the value in function PHP

Tags: php

I am facing some problem about return value, now i can return back with variable but it automatic separate it become 4 array. Below is my data when i used json_decode `$json_template = json_decode($json_body,true);` function

```
{
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "environment": "900"
}
```

after that i need to change the value by merge variable so i use Map function:

```php
$map = new Map($json_template);
$maps = $map->map(function($key, $value){
            if($key == 'password'){
                 $value = 'test';
            }
            return array($key=>$value);
        });
```

It result is become:

```
[
    {
        "username": ""
    },
    {
        "password": "test"
    },
    {
        "environment": "900"
    }
]
```

But i expected my result will come out like

```
{
    "username": "",
    "password": "test",
    "environment": "900"
}
```

what should i add or change the code?

Comment: Try this: `return $value;` because docs says `Returns the result of applying a callback to each value` It should helps you.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Emil Hong Heng Qin i updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc about the map method:

> Returns the result of applying a callback to each value

and:

> The callable should return what the key will be mapped to in the
>   resulting map.

It means you only need to return the modified `value` instead of an array `{key:value}`.

This is a working example on my machine (PHP 7.0 CLI):

```
$json_template = json_decode('
   {
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "environment": "900"
  }
', true);

$map = new \Ds\Map($json_template);
$maps = $map->map(function($key, $value){
     if($key == 'password'){
          $value = 'test';
     }
     return $value;
});

print_r($maps->toArray());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [username] =>
    [password] => test
    [environment] => 900
)
```

Comment: ya this one i also tried but the result come out is 
{ "","test","900"}, it skip the variable

Comment: also have you tried removing the false param in json_decode ?

Comment: @EmilHongHengQin and you are converting back with toArray() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
$json_template = json_decode($json_body,true);
foreach($json_template as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'password'){
        $json_template[$key]= 'test';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, still no work, even it change inside, it did not return back to the '$json_template'